# angular-ui-bootstrap typeahead causes form to be invalid if empty

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I have embedded the angular-ui-boothstrap typeahead in a directive. ([Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r4he3JLapu5rsugbvx3M?p=preview))
This directive is embedded within a form. The type-ahead is supposed to be optional, and the user should be allowed to submit the form even if no fruit is selected. However, the typeahead makes the form invalid if it's wrapped within a directive, and if the user hasn't selected any value.

If the typeahead is NOT within a directive, it works just fine.

Is there any way I can make the form valid even if the typeahead (in the directive) has no value?

```
<fruit-picker ng-model="fruitNameDirective" required="false" fruits="fruits"></fruit-picker>
```

Comment: Without seeing what save() does I can only guess. Firstly novalidate does not tell angular not to validate. That is used for telling the browser not to do native validation. You might just try ng-required=false in your input.

Comment: Scott, thanks for the feedback. I have tried to use hg-required, but that didn't help. The save() function calls the API, but the problem is the save button is never enabled if the typeahead is empty.

Comment: I updated the question & provided a Plunkr link which replicates the problem.